# How to emulate rsync into cp to copy all files from source that dont exist in destination disk and update existing ones?

Tags: file-transfer, rsync, cp, copy

Rsync is halting when reading bad sectors, then the hdd is going in a very bad mode than needs special rescue. It is the 3rd time that this happens to my disks. The disk was very functional except for bad sectors. Note that previously was double checked with e2fsck and was ok.

I can think that may disk try to reallocate the files that were read on bad sector by itself while rsync is operating and some problems arisen there. I really dont know. Therefore, I would like to follow another method of copying stuff except rsync that may be less destructive to my disks.

I have rsync to delete files that are not in proper place and in size, from source in destination. This is very quick and efficient. Now, I want to emulate some of the behavior of rsync into cp in order to copy all files and properly to update files.

I would like to try this command:
`cp -v -dR --copy-contents -f -n --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`

```
v: verbose
d: same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
R: recursive
--copy-contents of special files 
-f: if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again
(This command is only useful in appending stuff in files? )
-n: do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
-p: same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```

However, I have files that may have more data (than empty space) than in backup. Size is standard for each file and it is preallocated to disk. I dont know how to ensure to copy these files over the old ones with cp. I dont care to delete the whole file and copy it over.

Comment: Have you tried `rsync --ignore-errors`? Or, if you really think that trying to _read_ a file with `rsync` causes problems not to `rsync` but to the disk or the file system, then why do you think that reading them with any other tool wouldn't cause the same problems? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes i have tried that in rsync command for deletion in destination, not from copying from source.  I dont want to get another disk off cause of rsync. I think that rsync and cp will have different behaviour how they read and copy stuff when encountering bad sectors. I think cp is less heavy in reading and copying stuff when encountering bad sectors. I dont know what will do cp when encountering bad sectors. It may stop copying entirely the file, and it goes to the next one or stop.

Comment: Note that both disks are usb HDD connected to powered USB hub (v2). this may has also complications with rsync data transfer for when reading bad blocks? dont know.

Comment: "I think that rsync and cp will have different behaviour how they read [...]" "I think cp is less heavy in reading [...]" What do you base these thoughts on? What do you mean by "less heavy"? If you want to read as much of a file as you can, even in case of error, then you're looking for `ddrescue`. Other that that, I think both `cp` and `rsync` just simply read the file, and if they encounter an error then they jump to the next file, or completely abort. I don't see how they could behave substantially differently, and how that could be the key to save data from a broken disk.

Comment: My basic question is to use cp instead of rsync. I know that using rsync failed 3 disks of mine. This may has to do with software, usbs, disk cache (deactivated), dont know. The only way to de-halt the system is to turn off the disk (linux has problems here - discussed elsewere), rsync may utilize cache/ I/O in a specific way. I dont know if cp will create same problems with rsync when will encounter bad blocks. I will try it and see. I have not study the functions of rsync and cp, so dont know. I am a user i know that 3 disks failed when used rsync. One was very well checked with e2fsck.

Comment: You think there are different ways of reading a file. rsync uses some harsh method, which, if encounters some failure, makes the situation even worse by bringing your hdd to a "a very bad mode than needs special rescue". But, on contrary, cp would read using some gentle method, which, in case of failure, at least leaves the disk usable and you can continue by reading more files. That's not how it works. But go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: Also, read about XY Problem at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem, and ask about your actual goal. What do you actually want to achieve? E.g. you have a faulty hard drive and you want to rescue as much data as you can before destroying it?